# encoding ampersand in asp.net mvc kendo grid column filter

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

While filtering the column values of the Kendo grid in asp.net mvc application if we use the text containing ampersand i.e. "some & value" , it throws a unterminated string error. The reason is that the "&" needs to be encoded in the query string. 
How to do it? Which event of the kendo grid should this be done at and how?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#grid").kendoGrid({
      //...
        columns: [
           {
               field: "Column containing HTML",
               encoded: false
           }
        ]          
      });
 });
```

Comment: I am using MVC template not the JS way. Also, I am looking to encode the query string while filtering on a column, not just show column values. Thanks.

Comment: @dotnetter if this answered your question, mark the answer as accepted - this will help future people visiting this question.  If now, then leave a comment and me or someone else may be able to answer what you need

Comment: No, it didnt answer and thats why i left a comment. I need to encode the query string with the filter value while filtering in Kendo grid with MVC template.